# Overlap between user site and repository site

Tags: github-pages

If you create a GitHub repository named *<username>.github.io*, the repository gets hosted at *https://<username>.github.io/*. If you then create a directory named *<directory>* in this repository, this directory gets hosted at *https://<username>.github.io/<directory>/*.

If you create a GitHub repository named *<repository>*, it gets hosted at *https://<username>.github.io/<repository>/*.

What happens if you create *both* repositories and *<directory>* is the same as *<repository>*?

Answer (score 2):

As of now, if you create directory *<a>* in repository *<username>.github.io* and create another respository called *<a>*, the repository called *<a>* takes precedence. Thus, *https://<username>.github.io/<a>/index.html* points to *https://github.com/<username>/<a>/blob/main/index.html*.

This was verified empirically. I don't think this behavior is documented anywhere.